# Can You remove a blank background from an icon with CSS?

Tags: html, css

i am trying to remove the blank background from a image downloaded from google, since it does show up on my website.

is it possible to do it with a css line? or do i need to download a particular image format?
the thing is if I set a background image the icon won't blend in.

Comment: *"since it does show up on my website"* Then it is not blank. Please add the image in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icons insense ***"font icons"*** ? or ***normal image*** as icons,if you are using normal images as a icon,you can use transparent image format such as "***PNG file format***",so that the image can blend nicely with your background